# Merge cell from multiple columns into 1 cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue on how to merge cell from multiple columns into 1 cell.

```
Sub MergeCells()
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng In Range("J3:J" & LastRow)
rng = rng & rng.Offset(0, 1) & rng.Offset(0, 2) & rng.Offset(0, 3) & rng.Offset(0, 4) & rng.Offset(0, 5)
Next

End Sub
```

The issue am having is it the macro stop once reach blank cell.

I am expecting the macro to run through the excel without stopping once reach blank cell.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Check the value of `LastRow`.

Comment: Yes, I do know but I'm just wanted to built a macro so everything can be automated.

Comment: @SiddharthRout could you elaborate please.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `For Each rng In Range("J3:J" & LastRow)` and check what is the value of `LastRow`. Then manually check the worksheet. Are the the same?

Comment: Perfect thank you, `For Each rng In Range("J3:J" & LastRow)` I have changed to `For Each rng In Range("J3:J1000" & LastRow)` and it worked.

Comment: Your 'solution' will cause an error if LastRow is higher than 999.. Please follow SiddharthRout's comment to examine why it's stopping before you're expecting it to.

Comment: If `LastRow` is 1000 your solution would try and go to cell `J10001000` and give you an error instead.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I have follow @SiddharthRout solution though J3:J1000 is absolutely fine. Everything is working perfectly.

Comment: No. You have misunderstood what I was suggesting. Please re-read what I was asking you to do. **1.** Did you try what @CLR posted below? Ensure you have set the correct worksheet name at `Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")` **2.** Ensure that you are using the correct column to find the last row. For example, If Column `A` has more rows then `J` then use `A` instead of `J`.  Or better, use [.Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba/11169920#11169920) to find the last row in the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sub MergeCells()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change this to the correct sheet name
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In sht.Range("J1:J" & LastRow).Cells
        With rng
            .Value = .Value & .Offset(, 1).Value & .Offset(, 2).Value & .Offset(, 3).Value & .Offset(, 4).Value & .Offset(, 5).Value
        End With
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, I have now successfully have a working macro.

Comment: I would recommend trying this code @TK4795. If it still doesnt work then find the correct last row as mentioned in my comment below your question.